# Display Array List in Accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of different times .How can I display the array elements like in the photo below .

```
const doctorSchedule =["08:00","08:10","08:20","08:30","08:40","08:50","09:00","09:10","09:20","09:30","09:40","09:50","10:00","10:10","10:20","10:30","10:40","10:50",]
```

[image: photo]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which piece of code is not working as you'd expect?

Comment: As of now I am using a multi-dimensional Array List in the front-end ,so its easy to organize the times ,but since I am getting a One dimensional Array from the backend I can't figure out how to display it .So can you help ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time slots by putting them into buckets based on the hour. After you group them, you can iterate through the entries and create accordion items for each hour and generate radio buttons for each of the time slots in the hour bucket.

```js
const doctorSchedule = [
  "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50",
  "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50",
  "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50",
];

const slots = doctorSchedule.reduce((acc, time) =>
  ((hour) => ({ ...acc, [hour]: [...(acc[hour] ?? []), time] }))
  (parseInt(time.split(':')[0], 10)), {});

$('.accordion').append(Object.entries(slots).map(([hour, times]) =>
  $('<div>')
    .addClass('accordion-item')
    .append($('<h2>')
      .addClass('accordion-header')
      .attr('id', `heading-${hour}`)
        .append($('<button>')
          .addClass('accordion-button collapsed')
          .prop('type', 'button')
          .attr('aria-expanded', 'true')
          .attr('aria-controls', 'collapseOne')
          .attr('data-bs-toggle', 'collapse')
          .attr('data-bs-target', `#collapse-${hour}`)
          .text(`${(hour + '').padStart(2, '0')}:00`)))
    .append($('<div>')
      .addClass('accordion-collapse collapse')
      .attr('id', `collapse-${hour}`)
      .attr('aria-labelledby', `#heading-${hour}`)
      .append($('<div>')
        .addClass('accordion-body')
        .append(times.map(time =>
          $('<div>')
            .addClass('form-check form-check-inline')
            .append($('<input>')
              .addClass('form-check-input')
              .prop('type', 'radio')
              .attr('name', 'time-slot'))
            .append($('<label>')
              .addClass('form-check-label')
              .text(time))
            ))))));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample"></div>
</div>

<!--

Notes:

* https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/
* https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/

-->
```